Programmatically accessing user-selected MediaItems without repeated User Intervention (Google Photos API Update)
According to the upcoming March 2025 update for the Google Photos Library API, it appears that the only way to programmatically access mediaItems not created by the app is by using the Picker API, requiring the user to manually select photos each time.
Question:
Once a user has selected mediaItems through the Picker API, is there a way to programmatically access those specific items again later without requiring further user intervention? Or am I missing something?
Development environment:

Ruby on Rails


There is no way to do this. The base URLs generated by the API expire after 60 minutes according to the documentation, and the sessions also expire. I assume they don't want apps to have permanent access to photos in case the user forgets or the app gets hacked. The best thing to do is to probably download a copy of the photo and store it on your servers. I thought they wanted a similar flow to the Google Drive Picker API, but that one doesn't even function without a restricted scope that already gives you access to the user's full drive.
